# ssh works in terminal but not through Python

Tags: python, ssh

I am trying to write data to a disk on a remote machine via ssh using a Python script. However it is giving an error of `dd: /dev/xbd2d: Device not configured.`

```
import argparse
import os
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='basis')
parser.add_argument("-g", default=1, help="")
args = parser.parse_args()
volume = args.g
instance_ip=10.1.12.3
cmd_ssh='ssh -tt -i basis.pem root@'+instance_ip+ ''' "date | dd of=/dev/xbd2d"'''
os.system(cmd_ssh)
```

What is quite unusual is that if use the command:

```
ssh -tt -i basis.pem root@10.1.12.3 "date | dd of=/dev/xbd2d"
```

in a terminal, it executes correctly without any problem and writes the data to the disk. I wrote the same script in C++ and it worked fine but for some reason Python gives me `dd: /dev/xbd2d: Device not configured.`

Comment: Presumably `instance_ip` should be a string (as it's written it's a syntax error). Also have you tried using `subprocess.Popen` instead of `os.system`. With `shell=True` if needed.

Comment: ok @ Eran , i haven't tried subprocess.Popen so i'll do that right away. but i did try the standard Popen and it also gave that error

Comment: still getting the same error with subprocess.Popen @Eran

Comment: As @Eran says, the code you have shown cannot possibly run, because of the missing quotes around the ip address. Please make sure that the code you post is runnable and actually demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the quotes around the variable and also using \" instead of the triple quotes solved my problem as recommended by Eran

```
import argparse
import os
import time

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='basis')
parser.add_argument("-g", default=1, help="")
args = parser.parse_args()
volume = args.g
instance_ip=10.1.12.3
cmd_ssh="ssh -tt -i basis.pem root@"+str(instance_ip)+" \"date | dd of=/dev/xbd2d\""
os.system(cmd_ssh)
```